# How to pass a regular expression to a function

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a function that accepts more than one arguments. I am also passing a string with regular expression in it. But when it is getting `eval`uated others parameters are getting messed up.

Code is like below -

```
function foo() {
    eval DIR_NAME='$'$1
    MAX_DEPTH=$2
    eval FILE_PATTERN=$3
    RETENTION_PERIOD=$4
    eval MOVE_PATH='$'$5
    find . -maxdepth "$MAX_DEPTH" -type f -name "$FILE_PATTERN" -mtime +"$RETENTION_PERIOD" -print | ...
}

DIR_NAME="/my/path"
MAX_DEPTH=2
FILE_PATTERN="*.txt"
RETENTION_PERIOD=30
TARGET_DIRECTORY="/move/to/path"

foo DIR_NAME $MAX_DEPTH $FILE_PATTERN $RETENTION_PERIOD TARGET_DIRECTORY
```

Now the problem is at the `find` command `$FILE_PATTERN` is getting expanded and substituting itself with all the `.txt` file in the path and `RETENTION_PERIOD`, `MOVE_PATH` variables are getting substituted by other `.txt` files.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no need to use `eval` here. Use indirect variable reference of `BASH`.
2. `*.txt` is a glob pattern not regex and you should pass it quoted and use quotes inside in assignment to prevent shell expansion
3. Don't use all uppercase variable names to avoid clash with shall's internal environment variables.
4. Use `local` inside the function to define local variables to avoid overwriting global variables.

You can use:

```
foo() {
    local dir_name="${!1}"
    local max_depth="$2"
    local file_pattern="$3"
    local retention_period="$4"
    local move_path="${!5}"

    find . -maxdepth "$max_depth" -type f -name "$file_pattern" -mtime +"$retention_period" -print | ...
}
```

Then call it as:

```
dir_name="/my/path"
max_depth=2
file_pattern='*.txt'
retention_period=30
target_directory="/move/to/path"

foo dir_name "$max_depth" "$file_pattern" "$retention_period" target_directory
```